# How to use SoundCloud API in Android Project.?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, soundcloud

I am trying to develop an app using the `SoundCloud` API. I've generated the cient_id, client_secret, username and password etc. I've also imported all API related java files, like- `ApiWrapper.java`,`CloudApi.java`, `CountingMultipartActivity.java` and `Request.java` file.However ,I am getting error in Request.java File. I am posting the [link](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper) from where i get the API files.

When I am executing the app then i am getting following errors in `LogCat`.:-

```
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3071)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3066)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  ... 11 more
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1186)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:591)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:532)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper.safeExecute(ApiWrapper.java:565)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper.requestToken(ApiWrapper.java:263)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper.login(ApiWrapper.java:149)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.example.footballchants.SoundCloudManager.init(SoundCloudManager.java:41)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.example.footballchants.SoundCloudManager.<init>(SoundCloudManager.java:32)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.example.footballchants.SoundCloudManager.getInstance(SoundCloudManager.java:27)
10-21 12:41:15.096: E/AndroidRuntime(13524):  at com.example.footballchants.FindChantsActivity.onHomeClick(FindChantsActivity.java:127)
```

**API:**

```
public class SoundCloudManager {
    //starting of Singleton
    private static SoundCloudManager mInstance = null;
     ApiWrapper wrapper;

    public static SoundCloudManager getInstance()
    {
        if(mInstance== null)
        {
            mInstance= new SoundCloudManager();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    private SoundCloudManager(){
        init();
    }
    //ending of Singleton.

    public void init()
    {
        ApiWrapper wrapper = new ApiWrapper("XXX", "XXX", null, null);

        try {
            wrapper.login("XXXX", "XXXX");
            HttpResponse resp = wrapper.get(Request.to("/me"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return wrapper;

    }

}


Now i develop in RingtonesActivity. In the RingtonesActivity i used Singletun class, in OnHomeClick(). But i am not getting any error, stil my app is getting crash.

public class RingtonesActivity extends Activity {


    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Integer> drawableData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private RingtonesMusicAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtones);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            drawableData.add(R.drawable.phone_small_icon);
        }

        adapter = new RingtonesMusicAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_ringtones_row,
                drawableData);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ringtones, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onHomeClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        SoundCloudManager sound = SoundCloudManager.getInstance();
      //  sound.init();
        System.out.println("Yuuuhuuu");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onHomeClick()` method runs in the UI thread and calls `SoundCloudManager.getInstance()`, which then tries to Login the wrapper. That is not possible from the UI thread because it must access the Internet. Run the SounCloud API calls in a Background thread.

Comment: how to import souldcloud java-wrapper-api https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper library into my android app